# FileNotFoundError in python

Tags: python, encryption, file-not-found

I have an issue with FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: and i think it have to do with my visual studio code as on other PC it works. In debug console it prints the acctual name of the file Maybe you have any clues what could it be?

```
questionPass = [{'type': 'password','message': 'Enter your password','name': 'password'}]  

questionFile = [{'type': 'input','message': 'Please provide file name','name': 'io_file'}]

questionED = [ {'type': 'list','name': 'EncryptionDecryption','message': 'Please select to encrypt or decrypt the chosen file','choices': ['encrypt', 'decrypt']}]

password_provided = prompt(questionPass)
password = json.dumps(password_provided).encode('UTF-8') # Convert to type bytes
password_decoded = password.decode()
password = json.loads(password_decoded)['password'].encode()

salt = b'salt_' 
kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
length=32,
salt=salt,
iterations=100000,
backend=default_backend())

key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))

iof = prompt(questionFile)
io_file1 = json.dumps(iof)
io_file = json.loads(io_file1)['io_file']

ch = prompt(questionED)
cho = json.dumps(ch)
choice = json.loads(cho)['EncryptionDecryption']

#encryption part
if choice=='encrypt':        

    with open(io_file, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()

    fernet = Fernet(key)
    encrypted = fernet.encrypt(data)

    with open(io_file, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(encrypted)

    print ("\nEncryption part was done successfully")
    time.sleep(3)

 #decryption part     
elif choice=='decrypt':
    try:

        with open(io_file, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()

        fernet = Fernet(key)
        decrypted = fernet.decrypt(data)

        with open(io_file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(decrypted)
        print ("\nDecryption part was done successfully")
        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        print("Something went wrong. Please restart program and try again!")
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Used libraries just in case:
from __future__ import print_function, unicode_literals
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import cryptography
import base64
import os
import time
import json
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.kdf.pbkdf2 import PBKDF2HMAC
from PyInquirer import style_from_dict, Token, prompt, print_json
from examples import custom_style_2

Comment: This means that `io_file = json.loads(io_file1)['io_file']` is not returning a path that exists on your workstation.

Comment: @jordanm what shall i need to do in this case?

Comment: Fix the path to the file in your json or place the file or directory where it should be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FileNotFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658856/filenotfounderror)