# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Interview-part2.mp3' - pydub

Tags: python-3.x, directory, file-not-found, pydub, audiosegment

I am trying to convert a .mp3 file into a .wav file based on [this website][1].

I have set my working directory to the location that stores both the python script and the .mp3 file, and tried running the code below:

```
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment

#files
src = 'Interview-part2.mp3'
dst = 'Interview-part2.wav'
    
#Convert mp3 to wav
sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-f647e282d13d>", line 1, in <module>
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(src)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 796, in from_mp3
    return cls.from_file(file, 'mp3', parameters=parameters)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 651, in from_file
    file, close_file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(file, 'rb', tempfile=False)

  File "C:\Users\20200016\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Interview-part2.mp3'
```

Instead of only providing the audio file, I have also tried:

`src = DIRECTORY+'Interview-part2.mp3'`

But this resulted in a FileNotFoundError as well.

What causes this error, and what can I do to overcome it?
[1]: https://pythonbasics.org/convert-mp3-to-wav/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a FileNotFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658856/why-am-i-getting-a-filenotfounderror)

Comment: No, that's not it. I have set my working directory correctly and the name of the .mp3 file is correct as well.

Comment: How are you setting your working directory? Can you share your project structure? From where are you running your Python script?

Comment: What do you mean by project structure? I just used: `os.chdir(DIRECTORY)`

Comment: Check if `os.getcwd()` reports the expected directory.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it does

Comment: `os.listdir()` also shows `'Interview-part2.mp3'` as one of the files in the directory

Comment: Apparently you do not *have set my working directory correctly*, because if you had, you wouldn't be having this issue. Specify the full path name of the file by hard-coding it. Does that fix the issue? If so, then you've not set your working directory properly.

Comment: I have set it correctly. Otherwise, I wouldnt see the correct files when running `os.listdir()`

Answer (score 0):

A good start for debugging this would be to expand `src` to an absolute path, and make sure it resolves to what you expect.

```py
>>> src = 'Interview-part2.mp3'
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath(src)  # Result might strongly vary
'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\Interview-part2.mp3'
```

Answer (score 0):

use "." for absolute path in windows.

example: I have audio ext **.mp3** in folder **audio** `./audio/1-18 TOEFL Exercise 4.mp3`.