# How can I solve this problem: Python can't read my file

Tags: python

```
with open('Passwords.txt') as passwords:
    for line in passwords:
        print(line)
```

I just typed this code and it gives me

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Passwords.txt'
```

and I'm sure that this file in the same folder that I've put python file in. That's Proof:
[Files in the same folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INAU0.png)

Comment: From where are you running your script ? If you are running you script like this: ‘python mypath/myscript.py this will never work. You need to run you script from the root folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a FileNotFoundError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658856/why-am-i-getting-a-filenotfounderror)

Comment: FileNotFoundError is raised when you try to open a file but that file is not found. can you check if the file is in the same place that contains your code?

Answer (score -2):

You should first enter the full path, here is an example:

```
with open(r'/home/user/Documents/Passwords.txt') as passwords:
    # and don't forget this
    content = passwords.readlines()
    for line in passwords:
        print(line)
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with ```FileNotFoundError```

Comment: Nah it just defines each line to this variable (Content) as a list 
The program can not read the file

Comment: yeah it did but just I want to make my program read the file without giving the absolute path. that's because If i give this program to someone he hasn't to put the program in a specific place
does that make sense?

Comment: @Youssef, sorry but you didn't mention that in your question