# Raising FileNotFoundError when running script through SnakeViz

Tags: python, snakeviz

When I run my script from the IDE I don't get a problem. But when I run it using `python -m cProfile <script_file_name>` it raises a FileNotFoundError?

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.read_excel(<file_name>)
```

Comment: Probably the IDE has a different working directory and you are using a relative path…

Answer (score 0):

As @Grady Player mentioned in the comment, it's probably a [relative path](https://networkencyclopedia.com/relative-path/) issue.

First of all, try the file's full path; for example: "D:\some_folder\a.xlsx"

If it works, it means you are setting the path wrongly at first place.

Then, you may try to run following code for learning your IDE's working directory.

```
#importing the os module
import os

#to get the current working directory
directory = os.getcwd()

print(directory)
```

It surely gives you an idea about the relative path, so that you can create the relative path correctly.

Also, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658856/why-am-i-getting-a-filenotfounderror) about the `FileNotFoundError`.

Comment: when I try to print the directory, it prints the right directory of where the file is located in, but when it runs it says the file is not found

Comment: Did you try to give full path at first place?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way solution from Youtube (Channel Name: **mCoding**) :

```
import cProfile, pstats, pandas

with cProfile.Profiel() as pr:
    pandas.read_excel(<File_Name>)


stats = pstats.Stats(pr)
stats.dump_stats(filename="<stats_file_name>.prof")
```

and in the terminal do:

```bash
snakeviz <stats_file_name>.prof
```