# What is going on? I am using Python to fetch a directory with os but it's not working

Tags: python, directory, operating-system

[image: (Sorry people who use screen readers. Image of error and code as well as directory. The image explains it all.]

I am creating a decision tree and I give it a picture of either a cat or dog and it will decide whether it can detect if it is a cat or dog. I created a directory in my project called 'Images' and put a picture of a dog in it. Yet os cannot find the directory. I have tried many different types of ways to fetch the directory but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658856/why-am-i-getting-a-filenotfounderror

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304044/pycharm-current-working-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've messed up your directory structure in the script:

- On line 19 you append a category name to `Images` folder;
- After that, you're looking for the images in `Images\\Dog` and `Images\\Cat` (`listdir` on line 20), but `Cat` and `Dog` folders don't exist inside `Images`.

Either create `Cat` and `Dog` directories inside `Images` and move pictures there or change your code according to the file structure.